Setting Cookie to Secure in Production Breaks Authentication
I am using express-session for authentication in my Express application. Here is the code I have so far:
app.use(
  session({
    store: new RedisStore({ client: redis }),
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
      secure: true,
      httpOnly: true,
      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30, // 30 days
    },
  })
);

I have noticed that when I set the secure parameter to true, I am unable to access req.session values after setting them. This even occurs when I am have deployed my site to an https url. However, when I set secure to false, the req.session object contains the fields I expect.
Why does this happen? I understand that secure should be false when using http/testing with localhost, but I thought we should set secure to true in production/HTTPS settings.
Thanks.

Hi, Which is your hosting partner ?

As you know, while using express-session middleware, a cookie will be sent from the server to the client on its first request. And every subsequent request from the same client, will carry the same cookie, so that a session with respect to a particular login is maintained. However, whenever this cookie circulation breaks, the session maintenance will also be broken.
You have seen in your case, the session object has lost its values set in the previous session. This could happen because of two reasons.
a) The server did not send the cookie to the client
b) The client had not returned the same cookie
Please see below a case wherein the server did not send the session cookie to the client. This case occurred while hosting with render.com.
The following code would reproduce the reported case in render.com. The server will not send the session cookie to the clients.
app.use(
  session({
    secret: 'keyboard cat',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: { secure: true },
  })
);

The reason for this issue in render.com is that the express server will be behind a proxy server. While express will be running behind a proxy, the req.protocol will have an impact.
Please see the below codes demonstrating it.
…
console.log(req.protocol)  // will print http even in production with an https request
…

However, if trust proxy setting is done, then this issue would be fixed.
…
app.set('trust proxy', 1);
console.log(req.protocol)  // will print https in production
…

Since req.protocol without the proxy trusting statement is http, then a secure session cookie will not be sent to the client. Please see below the quote from Express documentation.

X-Forwarded-Proto can be set by the reverse proxy to tell the app
whether it is https or http or even an invalid name. This value is
reflected by req.protocol.

This is the reasoning behind this error as it can be understood from the documentation, if someone can shed more light on this by providing more evidence, please do so and help us.
Therefore while hosting in render.com, for express applications, it is mandatory to have to set the trust proxy statement.
You may please see if the session cookie is being stored under browser option - Application/Storage/Cookies, for Google Chrome. If not, then the server has failed to send the session cookie to the client. Please see if your server is behind a proxy, and try the trust proxy statement, we have discussed.
Citations:
Express behind proxies
